# C# trigger a Jenkins job with parameters

Tags: c#, jenkins

I'm trying to use C# to trigger a remote Jenkins job which has parameters.  The job triggers, but I have two problems.  First, the parameter is not being received by Jenkins, and two, I'm receiving no response from Jenkins.  Here is my code snippet:

`string url = "http://172.30.25.33:8080/job/CloudTeam/job/Tests/job/TestJob/buildWithParameters";

```
        using (var wb = new WebClient())
        {
            string json = @"{""parameter"": [{""testvar"" : ""user""" + @"""}]`";


                           //return json;

            string password = "mypassword";
            string username = "myuser";

            string basicAuthToken = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
            wb.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + basicAuthToken;

            wb.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";

            return wb.UploadString(url, json);
        }`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft does not recommend using [WebClient API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=netframework-4.7.2) for new development. Instead, they recommend using [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.7.2).

I would recommend using NewtonSoft's Json.NET (or similar library) to build the JSON data instead of crafting it by hand.

Have you tried using a tool like Postman to validate the request?

Comment: I've not tried that other Microsoft library, I'm not even sure how to use it.  I don't mind crafting the JSON by hand at the moment, the big problem is that Jenkins jobs are simply not getting the parameters needed.  I've verified via Postman that the parameters are not received.

Comment: Do you get an HTTP response from the Jenkins server? Is it a 200 or a 500 series response? 

Based on the information on this [link](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build), you can also do this with GET request by putting the parameters on the URL, for example: server/job/myjob/buildWithParameters?token=TOKEN&PARAMETER=Value. You'll need to put your authentication info in the token parameter.